# Accessing hundreds of files as fast as possible

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

So I have a program that will take in up to 1000 paths to files and the idea is to read 3 specific bytes to return the date which is all fine.

The problem start when it starts and the memory usage flies up towards the max and within a few seconds freezes my PC because of that.

I'm guessing the opening process uses up a few meg or something... Any ideas on how to achieve what I need without this massive memory usage?

NOTE: Files I am opening as something along the line of 15 GB

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    string paths[1000] = {};
    int date[3] = {0};

    cout << "Arg count: " << argc << endl;
    if (argc <= 1)
        paths[0] = "PRIV.EDB";
    else
        for(int i = 1;i<argc;i++){
            paths[i-1] = argv[i];
        }

    cout << "Start\n\n";
    for (int i=0;i<1000;i++)
    {
        if (paths[i].empty())
            break;
        cout << paths[i] << endl;
        ifstream pFile;
        pFile.open(paths[i], ios::binary);
        pFile.seekg(195);
        date[0] = pFile.get();
        date[1] = pFile.get();
        date[2] = pFile.get();
        cout << date[0] << " : " << date[1] << " : " << date[2] << " \n";
        cout << endl;
        pFile.clear();
        pFile.close();
    }
    cout << "Fin\n";

    if (argc <= 1)
        getchar();

    return date[0];
}
```

Comment: stream cost more to initialize than simple fopen. I guess pb come from that. You should time your code to see exactly where it spend time.

Comment: @ColdCat: No it doesn't. I recently wrote a simple test that reads/writes a large number of lines of text from/to a file, and using `scanf` is not faster than `cin`. Using `endl` does however make it significantly slower.

Comment: Which of the questions do you want help with? The question in your title ("as fast as possible") or the question in the text ("limit memory access")?

Comment: Opening a thousand files is always troublesome because (even assuming the MFT is locked in RAM) this means 1000 seeks. 1000 times 9 milliseconds is 9 seconds spent on seeking and doing nothing. Insofar, few optimizations will really help a lot.

Comment: @MatsPetersson The slowness of `endl` is most likely because it also explicitly flushes the stream. Just use e.g. `'\n'` if you want a newline, and let the system flush when needed instead.

Comment: @IInspectable I'm trying to read all the files as quick as possible, but the memory usage basically means i'm going to have to do it slower to keep up.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Yes that was implied in my message.

Comment: Since you are only ever reading 3 bytes from the first page (at offset 195), why not memory map the first 4k or each file... not like this will help with the seeking problem, but it addresses any possible issues with iostream.

Comment: You don't need to explicitly `clear` and `close` the file you open, since it's local inside the loop it will be done automatically each iteration of the loop as it goes out of scope.

Comment: There is nothing obvious that takes a lot of memory in your code - even with very long filenames, I'd expect it to not use more than a few megabytes.

Comment: It's almost certainly not his problem, but: if he'd use `std::vector` for the program arguments, then he could dimension them to `argc - 1` to begin with.  Although given what he does later, there's really no point in not leaving them as they are, and using `argv[i]` directly.

Answer (score 2):

Use memory-mapped files for better performance.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx

MSDN:

> These memory-mapped files are suitable for working with extremely
>   large source files

Wikipedia:

> The primary benefit of memory mapping a file is increasing I/O
>   performance, especially when used on large files... Accessing memory
>   mapped files is faster than using direct read and write operations for
>   two reasons. Firstly, a system call is orders of magnitude slower than
>   a simple change to a program's local memory. Secondly, in most
>   operating systems the memory region mapped actually is the kernel's
>   page cache (file cache), meaning that no copies need to be created in
>   user space.

For easy implementation see:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/interprocess.html

use:

boost/interprocess/file_mapping

boost/interprocess/mapped_region

Comment: Memory mapped files can increase file I/O performance **if** you are going to read the entire file. When reading 3 bytes at a fixed offset I would assume the sequence `CreateFile`, `SetFilePointer`, `ReadFile`, `CloseHandle` to be significantly faster.

Comment: @IInspectable as he says that "memory usage flies up towards the max and within a few seconds freezes my PC because of that." wouldn't the fact that no copies are created of the files might be very helpfull?

Comment: @IInspectable: `ReadFile` works via memory mapping as well, and it has to lock a page and do a memory copy. So although it involves one less Win32 API call, I wouldn't bet it's any faster. Also, `ReadFile` cannot easily make assumptions about how much data to prefetch, it will likely fetch the default 128k into the buffer cache. If you map only one page, the OS knows exactly that only 16 pages must be created and only one page (or 16 in the worst case) needs to be _fetched_. This reduces the number of stale pages and thus increases the likelihood of a cache hit (though only slightly).

Comment: @sara The limiting factor is **address space**. Mapping a file into a process consumes address space even if no copy is made.

Comment: That's a silly argument. If you have less than 64kB of contiguous address space left, you have an entirely different kind of problem.

Comment: @Damon sara suggested that if a file does not need to be copied it would not consume memory. This is wrong, as a file mapping still requires address space. Copying a file into a process provided buffer or mapping it into a process consumes the same amount of address space, memory that is no longer available to a process. To rephrase my statement: The limiting factor is address space, not available RAM, or whatever other mental model you may have made up to represent "memory".

Comment: @IInspectable Address space the limiting factor? no way.

Comment: @sara In a system that virtualizes memory, address space is the only resource limit. RAM is irrelevant. HDD space is important, but generally not an issue. When an application runs out of memory it usually runs out of address space (ignoring memory fragmentation for a moment). If you think this is wrong please provide an explanation. Simply saying "no way" is fairly vague.